# Можно ли не ставить ; в конце строки?

Tags: javascript

Как принято, можно ли не ставить ; в конце строки, а писать без них как в питоне?

Внимание: вопрос не о теоретической возможности, а о том, как принято.

Comment: +1 в "принято ставить". От себя бы порекомендовал выучить любой транспайлер (компилятор из специального разработанного для того языка в javascript - coffescript, typescript) и просто перейти на боле продвинутый язык.

Comment: @Etki я просто увидел, что можно не ставить и по питоновской привычке не ставил, а потом решил спросить, раз уж нахаляву.

Comment: Мухоморы тоже можно есть, только отравишься. Так и здесь, где-то проскочит, где-то нет. Вообще, принято писать правильный код.

Comment: @Дмитрий вопрос в том, как принято,а не в том, где **я** отравлюсь. Тем более, правила во многом совпадают с питоном.

Answer (score 2):

Принято ставить, во избежание неясностей, которые имеют место быть.
Можете почитать подробнее об этом вот [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/structure#semicolon):

> Важно, что вот такой код уже работать не будет:
>
> `alert("Сейчас будет ошибка")
>   [1, 2].forEach(alert)`
>
> Выведется только первый `alert`, а дальше — ошибка. Потому что перед
>   квадратной скобкой JavaScript точку с запятой не ставит, а как раз
>   здесь она нужна (упс!).
>
> Если её поставить, то всё будет в порядке:
>
> `alert( "Сейчас будет ошибка" ); 
>   [1, 2].forEach(alert)`
>
> Поэтому в JavaScript рекомендуется точки с запятой ставить. Сейчас
>   это, фактически, стандарт, которому следуют все большие проекты.

Comment: "В JavaScript перевод строки её заменяет, но лишь частично," - можно подробнее?

Comment: Я изменил ссылку, на статью с более подробной информацией и примерами.

Comment: Внутри скобок переводы строк игнорируются. Как и в питоне.

Comment: Также можете обратиться за примером к исходникам популярной библиотеки [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js)

Comment: Ой,нет, так, как в примере, питон не поступает. js ломаный, таки да :)

Comment: В каких еще случаях ecmascript не ставит ;?

Answer (score 0):

Принято ставить. Но это не строгое правило. 
Даже IntelliJ phpshorm и webstorm по умолчанию помечают строки без точки с запятой как требующие внимания.